# How to get data from /admin/products.json even if I'm logged out (so normal visitors can see data, too)?

Tags: rest, api, shopify, shopify-app

```
        if ( collectionId ) {
            var url ='/admin/products.json?published_status=published&limit=' + limit + '&page=' + filterPage + '&collection_id=' + collectionId;
        } else {
            var url = '/admin/products.json?published_status=published&limit=' + limit + '&page=' + filterPage;
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            headers: {
                'X-Shopify-Access-Token': '',
                // Would it fix my problem? If so, how to generate private token?
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            success: function(data){
            ...
            },
            error: {
            ...
            }
       });

// Works when logged in
// Does not work
```

I'm quite new to Shopify and don't understand how their REST works but thing I understood after long investigation is I need somehow authenticate my request every time I need products.json.

When I'm logged out of shopify, ajax redirects me to login page where I can click continue. But nothing happens.

If Access Token could help, how can I generate one?
I have red this course but this one is about public apps (even if he said that technical stuff is same for public and private).
https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/17056443-how-to-generate-a-shopify-api-token

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

You should explain what you mean better. Why can you not just render product JSON using Liquid if you feel you need it? All themes do that in their Javascript.

But, just in case you truly cannot easily do that for some weird reason, you could follow this advice below...

You need to stop right there! DO NOT try and access the backend data from the front end as that exposes your API token! Instead, there is a simple pattern for you to use:

- install a private App with access to your products in your store
- setup the App Proxy in that App using your Partner account in Shopify
- setup your App to receive a product ID, and return the specific JSON you want on the front end
- on the front end, you can now do a GET to that App and securely receive your data

Shopify stopped providing product details from the front-end as it left shops wide open to abuse from competitors.

Comment: Thank you, David!

I made custom ajax filter system for filtering products through tags, colors and types.

Your advice about rendering products in json on the view and get that in javascript is really great and I tried to implement that but collection.products or collections.all.products return only first 50 products. Do you how can I get all products?

Also about getting private app - can I then get ALL products with GET with all information I need (tags, images, price, etc) ?

Comment: You can paginate more than 50 products. But note that working with collection.all could kill your speed and cost you a lot of time. A private App could help you since you move a lot of your search and filter logic to code that runs fast, and returns results fast.

Comment: If I write paginate .. by 100 it stills returns 50 products. How can I achieve that?